# Flex Datagrid and finding number member variable of a class

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have two questions

1. How to populate a flex datagrid from an Arraycollection without specifying DataGridColumn's individually. Is there any custom datagrid available where I can pass the datasource arraycollection and see the data populated in the output.
2. Without knowing the structure / bluprint of an object is there anyway to find how many member variable that class have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your second question - there are 2 ways to accomplish this:

1. Using a for..in loop. This only works for *dynamically* added properties.
2. Using the describeType API. This will return a rich XML object describing an object, including all of its member variables as well as their visibility.

You can read more about these two techniques [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/usingas_8.html).

Comment: Oh great Thanks a lot (Performing object introspection). Is it possible to populate all the columns in a datagrid through this iteration like write a simple routine to generate the columns on the fly?

Comment: Yes you could iterate the introspection XML and create a DataGridColumn for each property you are interested in. You would just need to assign each column a dataField value corresponding to the property you want it to display.

Comment: Thanks Dude , for my requirement "List accessors as properties" works perfect. One more doubt , example# 3 from that URL(livedoc) has a comment "Do not get the property value if it is write only." , Does it refer to access specifier?

Comment: Yes, if the property lacks a public getter then it is write-only and there is no way you will be able to get its value.

Comment: Got you , I got the datagrid also working. .Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
       static public function getDetails(argData:Object , grid:DataGrid):void { 
            // Get the Button control's E4X XML object description.
            var classInfo:XML = describeType(argData);
            // List accessors as properties.
            var _columnList:Array = new Array();
            for each (var a:XML in classInfo..accessor) {
                // Do not get the property value if it is write only.
                var _column:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn;  
                // Setting properties  
                _column.headerText = a.@name;  
                _column.dataField = a.@name;  
                _column.width = 180;  
                _columnList.push(_column);   
            } 
            grid.columns = _columnList;
        }
```

Populated Datagrid through this routine , helps a lot debugging my result data.